# Facebook Login stopped working for Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I was working on a project where facebook login was required from the website. It was already implemented and was a working feature. However it recently stopped working and I get this error message.[image]

I already went to the facebook settings and changed the various settings such as domain, site URL and canvas URL. But it continues to show the same error. I am starting to suspect this might be an app approval issue more than anything else. Have any of you faced similar issues?

The app is written with Rails 3.2 and is using 'omniauth-facebook' gem for login.

Thanks

Comment: Which url are you trying to redirect to?

Comment: How do I find that out? The domain, site and canvas URL point to the my app's homepage (format is like xxxx.com). Apart from this, I didn't specify any explicit redirection URL

Comment: In the url in that dialog window it will contain redirect_url as one parameter

Comment: OK. This is the url in my dialog window:-
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup&domain=singapore.xxxx.com&scope=email&api_key=489180221137539&app_id=489180221137539&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&client_id=489180221137539&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D20%23cb%3Df1ecd610a%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fsingapore.xxxx.com%252Ff1127cdb38%26domain%3Dsingapore.xxxx.com%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df1b23751c8&origin=1&response_type=token%2Csigned_request

Comment: Seems like you should set the redirect url

Comment: I tried to add in all possible redirect URLs in the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" under advanced settings in the developer portal. It still returns the same message. 

Am I supposed to include the redirect URL somewhere while making the facebook login javascript call?

Also, why was this working earlier? It only stopped working recently after there was a facebook update to the developer portal/sdk